# Trying to obtain MD5 fingerprint for debug certificates, getting Errors

Tags: api, cmd, md5, keytool

While in the keytool directory I type in what I am supposed to as instructed by the Google code website.
**To generate an MD5 fingerprint of the debug certificate, first locate the debug keystore. By default, build tools create the debug keystore in the active AVD directory. The location of the AVD directories varies by platform:**

MY CODE IN CMD:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore C:\Documents and Settings\nwashington.android\debug.keystore -storepass an
droid -keypass android

MY ERROR:

keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, and is not a legal command

I have already checked:

-If the files are actually located in these directories

-Tried out this website: http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a35/Android-How-To-Set-Up-an-API-Key-for-Google-Maps.html

Please Help! 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462837/how-to-find-the-md5-fingerprint-of-my-android-app
This will surely help you , check out its cool :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you put the path to your debug keystore in quotes because Windows does not recognise spaces in Documents and Settings. Your command should be like this:

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys tore "C:\Documents and Settings\nwashington.android\debug.keystore" -storepass an droid -keypass android

Copy it just the way it is and paste it in your command prompt. It should be able to run !!!!